# How to cache asp.net mvc user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, caching, outputcache

I have a scenario where i want to apply cache on a user control in asp.net mvc 2.
I have applied

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

but user control output is not cached. I read on a blog that

> Html.RenderPartial method ignores any OutputCache directives on
>   the view user control

So, My question is how to apply cache on user control in Asp.Net MVC 2. Im rendering my user control in a MasterPage like this

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Widgets/Modulename"); %>
```

**Second Part of Question**

Can i apply caching on a Helper Method in Asp.Net MVC 2 like this

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "SidebarDetailsId")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on Phil Haack blog.

> http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx